# Split 2 url images to one

Tags: php, string, function

I have json data, what I parse.

```
{"response":[14516,{"id":310457,"from_id":-22759696,"to_id":-22759696,"date":1458731719,"post_type":"post","text":"Полиция Бельгии определила трех подозреваемых в теракте в аэропорту<br>.","attachment":{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":405948296,"aid":-7,"owner_id":-22759696,"user_id":100,"src":"http:\/\/cs628628.vk.me\/v628628040\/41d81\/DciVVyiqqOU.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/cs628628.vk.me\/v628628040\/41d82\/q2EumplfhhM.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/cs628628.vk.me\/v628628040\/41d80\/zaETzTkDLUs.jpg","width":600,"height":340,"text":"Original: http:\/\/cdn15.img22.ria.ru\/images\/139461\/56\/1394615611.jpg","created":1458731718,"post_id":310457,"access_key":"62c1447c0497a750ce"}},"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":405948296,"aid":-7,"owner_id":-22759696,"user_id":100,"src":"http:\/\/cs628628.vk.me\/v628628040\/41d81\/DciVVyiqqOU.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/cs628628.vk.me\/v628628040\/41d82\/q2EumplfhhM.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/cs628628.vk.me\/v628628040\/41d80\/zaETzTkDLUs.jpg","width":600,"height":340,"text":"Original: http:\/\/cdn15.img22.ria.ru\/images\/139461\/56\/1394615611.jpg","created":1458731718,"post_id":310457,"access_key":"62c1447c0497a750ce"}}],"comments":{"count":1},"likes":{"count":7},"reposts":{"count":0}}]}
```

I'm retrieving "src_big":"http://cs628628.vk.me/v628628040/41d82/q2EumplfhhM.jpg" for example. But this image, not in https://, i need to convert to https by the set of rules.

```
http://cs629401.vk.me/v629401896/3e689/pT5Z5oukzIE.jpg
https://pp.vk.me/c629401/v629401896/3e689/pT5Z5oukzIE.jpg
```

There u can see I have similar "c629401" and I need to change

> http://cs629401.vk.me/

to

> https://pp.vk.me/c629401/

this
Images can be with another link for example

```
http://cs628628.vk.me/v628628040/41d82/q2EumplfhhM.jpg
https://pp.vk.me/c628628/v628628040/41d82/q2EumplfhhM.jpg
```

Comment: .... what? Show us your code, it'll make it easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Following code using preg_match should be ok:

```
<?php
    $imgurl = "http://cs629401.vk.me/v629401896/3e689/pT5Z5oukzIE.jpg";
    $toremove = Array("s", "S");
    preg_match("#http://(.+)\.vk\.me/(.+)#", $imgurl, $matches);
    $simgurl = "https://pp.vk.me/" . str_replace($toremove, "", $matches[1]) . "/" . $matches[2];

    echo $simgurl . "\n";
```

https://pp.vk.me/c629401/v629401896/3e689/pT5Z5oukzIE.jpg

---

You can wrap it in a function to convert urls:

```
<?php

function convertUrl($url)
{
    $toremove = Array("s", "S"); // Letters to remove from matches[1] group
    preg_match("#http://(.+)\.vk\.me/(.+)#", $url, $matches);
    return "https://pp.vk.me/" . str_replace($toremove, "", $matches[1]) . "/" . $matches[2];
}

echo convertUrl("http://cs629401.vk.me/v629401896/3e689/pT5Z5oukzIE.jpg") . "\n";
```

https://pp.vk.me/c629401/v629401896/3e689/pT5Z5oukzIE.jpg

Comment: I have one problem yet, image converted, but, `http://cs543100.vk.me/v543100865/24b34/s1N2De6oQ70.jpg` `https://pp.vk.me/"C"543100/v543100865/24b34/s1N2De6oQ70.jpg`, but I have `https://pp.vk.me/CS543100/v543100865/24b34/s1N2De6oQ70.jpg`

Comment: @ATIKON Can you elaborate more about your problem? Any further details and / or source code will be appreciated.

Comment: @DevilaN your script putting pp.vk.me/ by replacing cs543100.vk.me/, when replacing there putting cs543100 correct, but i need to but c543100, without 's'

Comment: I see. Are there any rules when "s" should go out and when not?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. You can add / change letters which go out by adding / removing them from $toremove array.

Comment: @DevilaN i solved this problems about 30 minutes ago) But, many thanks)